# "Given p ⇒ q and q ⇔ r, use the Fitch system to prove p ⇒ r"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing

I'm having some difficulty understanding the Fitch system - could someone please break down and answer the aforementioned question for me?

I'm able to get to:

1. p => q                  Premise
2. q <=> r                 Premise 2
3. p                       Assumption
4. q                       Implication elimination 1,3
5. q => r                  Biconditional elimination 2
6. p => (q => r)           Implication introduction 3,5

My issue is that I don't know how to whittle 6. down into p=>r - I know the operation required could be called the inverse of implication distribution, but beyond that I'm stumped.

Help!

Comment: How exactly is your biconditional elimination rule defined?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

What you want to show is an implication $p \to r$, so you know that the last thing to happen is likely an implication introduction:

```
| 3. p      (assumption)
...
| n. r      (?)
6. p -> r   (->I, 3-n)
```

For an implication introduction, you need to have derived $r$ form assumption $p$. You already have $p$ as an assumption in l. 3, so you need to derive $r$ in that subproof. Now what are the formulas in your proof which you could get $r$ from? You've got $q \to r$ on line 5. Given the other conclusions and assumptions you have up until there, how do you think you could combine them to derive $r$? It's just one additional step. Once you got that figured out, you're done.

Comment: skilfully prompted and much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

*Edit:* Another answerer submitted a responce 30 seconds before mine, and their response does not give the entire answer, instead it gives a *hint*. As such I have marked my answer as a spoiler, which you can view by hovering your mouse over it if you wish to.

> Your proof is almost correct. Instead of making an implication introduction on line 6, make an implication elimination between 4 and 5 to arrive at $r$. Then perform your implication introduction to get $p\implies r$.

Full answer:

> \begin{align}1.&p => q&~Premise\\2.&q <=> r&~Premise\\3.&p&~Assumption\\4.&q&~Implication~elimination~1,3\\5.&q => r&~Biconditional~elimination~2\\6.&r&~Implication~elimination~4,5\\7.&p\implies r&~Implication~introduction~3,6\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your line 5 is incorrect. Typically, in a Fitch system, Biconditional elimination would be applied on two lines: one being the biconditional, and the second being one of the two sides of that biconditional, allowing you to infer the other side.

So, in this case, you'd infer $r$ from line 4 ($p \leftrightarrow r$) and 2 ($q$), and now the conditional introduction rule gives you exactly what you want.

Comment: It depends on the particular system.  In some Fitch systems, biconditional elimination might be the inference of a conditional from a biconditional.  Conditional elimination may them be applied as a separate inference.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Agreed. I just asked the OP how the rule is defined.